# Are there at least 45 variants of l'Hopital's Rule and how to prove variant with $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} f(x)= \lim\limits_{x\to a^+} g(x) = \infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

The following is a problem in Ch. 11 "The Significance of the Derivative" from Spivak's *Calculus*

> 56. To complete the orgy of variations on l'Hopital's Rule, use Problem 55 to prove a few more cases of the following general
>     statement (there are so many possibilities that you should select just
>     a few, if any, that interest you):
>
> If $\lim\limits_{x\to [\ ]} f(x)= \lim\limits_{x\to [\ ]} g(x) = \{\
>  \}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to [\ ]} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=(\ )$, then
> $\lim\limits_{x\to [\ ]}  \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=(\ )$. Here $[\ ]$ can be
> $a$ or $a^+$ or $a^-$ or $\infty$ or $-\infty$, and $\{\ \}$ can be
> $0$ or $\infty$ or $-\infty$, and $(\ )$ can be $l$ or $\infty$ or
> $-\infty$.

**First of all, given the problem statement above, is it accurate to say that there are at least $5\cdot 3 \cdot 3=45$ variations of L'Hopital's Rule?**

I've seen questions on proving L'Hopital's Rule but given that there are many variations on the rule, and the fact that the proofs are not all exactly the same (I've gone through at least ten so far), I'd like to ask about one particular variation that I can't seem to find a proof for.

When we let $[\ ]$ be $a$, $a^+$, or $a^-$ and let $\{\ \}$ be $\infty$, for example, I can't seem to come up with a proof.

**To cut to the chase, I'd like to know how to prove the following**

> If $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} f(x)= \lim\limits_{x\to a^+} g(x) = \infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=l$, then
> $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=l$.

The proofs of l'Hopital's Rule I have seen usually start by using the assumption that the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to [\ ]} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=(\ )$ exists to establish existence of $f'$ and $g'$ and $g'\neq 0$ on a certain interval $A$ that depends on what the limiting value is in the limits, ie what is chosen as the $[\ ]$ parameter.

Next the Mean Value Theorem is invoked to establish either that $g(x)\neq 0$ or $g(x)-g(a)\neq 0$ on interval $A$.

Then the Cauchy-Schwarz MVT is invoked to obtain some relationship of one of the forms

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}$$

$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)}$$

where $\alpha_x \in A$. At this point the limit of both sides is taken and we end up with the conclusion of the particular variant L'Hopital's Rule we are proving.

Obviously I skipped over a few steps in this description, but this is a general outline. I believe the issue I have for proving the statement I asked about above is application of MVT. If the limit of $f$ and $g$ when $x$ approaches $a$ is $\infty$, we can't use point $a$ to apply the MVT as is done in the proofs of all the other variations of L'Hopital's Rule as far as I can tell.

Comment: This may help: https://tmpfiles.org/dl/344350/lhopital.pdf

Comment: If the above link expired: https://tmpfiles.org/dl/344688/lhopital.pdf

Comment: The extended theorem in the document above is slightly different from the version of L'Hopital that I am asking about.

Answer (score 2):

**Assumptions**: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}g(x)=\infty\qquad (1)$$ and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}\frac{f’(x)}{g’(x)}=l\qquad (2)$$

**Assertion**: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=l$$

To prove the assertion, one needs to show that $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists \delta>0$ such that $$x\in (a,a+\delta)\Rightarrow \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-l\right|<\epsilon.$$

*Proof of Assertion*. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. By (2), there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that $$x\in (a,a+\delta_1)\Rightarrow \left|\frac{f’(x)}{g’(x)}-l\right|<\frac{\epsilon}2.$$

Let $$\epsilon_1=\min\left(\frac 12,\frac{\epsilon}{4(|l|+1)}\right).\qquad (3)$$

By (1), there exists $\delta$ with $0<\delta<\delta_1$ such that for $x\in (a,a+\delta),$ one has $\epsilon_{1,f}(x):=f(a+\delta_1)/g(x)$ satisfies $|\epsilon_{1,f}(x)|<\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_{1,g}(x):=g(a+\delta_1)/g(x)$ satisfies $|\epsilon_{1,g}(x)|<\epsilon_1.$

Now for the above $\delta>0$ and for $x\in (a,a+\delta)\subseteq (a,a+\delta_1),$ one has by Cauchy’s MVT that $$\frac{f’(\alpha_x)}{g’(\alpha_x)}=\frac{f(x)-f(a+\delta_1)}{g(x)-g(a+\delta_1)}=\frac{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-\epsilon_{1,f}(x)}{1-\epsilon_{1,g}(x)},$$ where $\alpha_x\in (x,a+\delta_1).$ It follows that $$\left|\frac{f’(\alpha_x)}{g’(\alpha_x)}-l\right|=\left|\frac{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-\epsilon_{1,f}(x)}{1-\epsilon_{1,g}(x)}-l\right|<\frac {\epsilon}2$$
$$\Rightarrow \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-\epsilon_{1,f}(x)-l(1-\epsilon_{1,g}(x))\right|<\frac {\epsilon}2(1-\epsilon_{1,g}(x))$$
$$\Rightarrow \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-l\right|-\left|l\epsilon_{1,g}(x)-\epsilon_{1,f}(x)\right|<\frac{\epsilon}2(1+\epsilon_1)$$
$$\Rightarrow \left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-l\right|<\frac{\epsilon}2(1+\epsilon_1)+(|l|+1)\epsilon_1\leq \frac {\epsilon}2\left(1+\frac 12\right)+\frac{\epsilon}4=\epsilon,$$ where the last estimate follows from (3). This proves the assertion. QED

Comment: How do we know that $|\epsilon_{1,f}(x)|<\epsilon_1$?

Comment: Since both $\epsilon_{1,f}(x)$ and $\epsilon_{1,g}(x)$ are of the form $C/g(x)$, where $C$ is a constant and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^+}g(x)=\infty$, we can choose a common $\delta>0$ such that $\delta<\delta_1$ and that $x\in (a,a+\delta)$ implies that $|\epsilon_{1,f}(x)|<\epsilon_1$ and $|\epsilon_{1,g}(x)|<\epsilon_1.$

Comment: I am at the third-to-last step, going to the second-to-last step. How do you go from $\frac{\epsilon}{2}(1-\epsilon_{1,g}(x))$ to $\frac{\epsilon}{2}(1+\epsilon_1)$? Isn't $-\epsilon_1<\epsilon_{1,g}(x)<\epsilon_1$? Shouldn't the last term in the second-to-last step be $\frac{\epsilon}{2}(1-\epsilon_1)$?

Comment: @evianpring It’s just triangle inequality. It’s true that $-\epsilon_1<\epsilon_{1,g}(x)<\epsilon_1$, so $-\epsilon_{1,g}(x)<\epsilon_1$. But your last suggestion is not correct.

Comment: How in the world do you come up with a proof so specific like this?

Answer (score 2):

There are not so many variants of l’Hôpital’s theorem: just $0/0$ and $\infty/\infty$.

You can simply prove them for the case
$$
\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}
$$
because the case for $x\to a^-$ follows by replacing $x\mapsto -x$ and the case $x\to\infty$ follows by replacing $x\mapsto 1/x$. The case $x\to a$ combines the two above.

Indeed, if we examine the last case, we have to do
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(1/x)}{g(1/x)}
$$
and it's simple to verify that the hypotheses are satisfied, so we want to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{-f'(1/x)/x^2}{-g'(1/x)/x^2}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f'(1/x)}{g'(1/x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}
$$
(if the limits exist, of course), by doing again $x\mapsto 1/x$. Similarly for $x\to-\infty$.

Thus the proofs you need are just two.

Actually, there is a third case (that however includes $\infty/\infty$) and is $\text{(anything)}/\infty$, where (anything) may also be “the limit does not exist”. You find the proof on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#General_proof).

Comment: $0/0$, $\infty/\infty$, and $-\infty/-\infty$ are three cases for the term in $\{\ \}$. But What about the variations that involve. But there are the terms in $(\ )$ and $[\ ]$. You didn't provide a reason why we can't say there are at least 45 variations. There do seem to be. Which of the 45 are you claiming is not possible?

Comment: @evianpring Do you find $-\infty/{-\infty}$ different from $\infty/\infty$? I don't. Maybe $-\infty/\infty$, but you can reduce to $\infty/\infty$ by changing one sign. Anyway, there are *formally* 45 cases, but as I showed you reduce the proof to two. And in my opinion it is very important to learn how to reduce one case to another.

Comment: I know those are equivalent basically, so yes, you are right, but I just wanted to confirm that in fact there are 45 different possibilities. Other than that, I am going through the calculations you suggested. I have posted below one calculation using the trick with changing $x$ and doing some manipulations with the resulting limits. I did the case with $x$ to $-x$ to prove the limit for $x\to a^-$ when we assume we have already proved the result when $x\to a^+$. One question I have is what happens if a function is only defined for $x>0$ or $x<0$? Does the trick you suggested still work?

Comment: What about the case when we change $x$ to $1/x$? What happens at $x=0$?

Comment: With regard to the $x$ to $1/x$ substitution, it seems this works when $x$ is approaching $0$, but what about for some $a^+$? Ie, we have $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} f= \lim\limits_{x\to a^+} g = \infty$ If we define $f_1(x)=f(1/x)$, $g_1(x)=g(1/x)$, then I'm not sure what to do with $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} f(1/x)$. And the thing is, my main question is precisely about this case.

Comment: @evianpring Sorry, but I don’t understand. With $x\mapsto 1/x$ a limit for $x\to\infty$ becomes a limit for $x\to0^+$, which is a particular case of $x\to a^+$. When you consider a limit for $x\to\infty$ it’s not restrictive to assume that the function is defined for $x>p$, for some $p>0$.

Answer (score 0):

In trying to understand the other answers, I had to fill in intermediate steps. I want to make those steps explicit here for future reference and to make sure I actually comprehended correctly.

Assume we are able to prove the following result

**Result 0**

> Assume that
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} g(x)=0$$
>
> and
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=l$$
>
> Then we can conclude that
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}
>  \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=l$$

(See Spivak, Ch. 11, Theorem 9 for an exact proof of this specific result).

According to the answer from @egreg, we can prove some further similar results using manipulations of limits. Here is an example of one such proof. I had to do all the steps to wrap my head around the operations with limits.

**Result 1**

> Assume that
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x\to a^-} f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a^-} g(x)=0$$
>
> and
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x\to a^-} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=l$$
>
> Then we can conclude that
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x\to a^-} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to a^-}
>  \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=l$$

Let $f_1(x)=f(-x)$ and $g_1(x)=g(-x)$.

Then (I believe according to [this result)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493780/prove-lim-limits-x-to-a-fx-lim-limits-x-to-a-f-x)

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} f_1(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} f(-x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a^-} f(x)=0$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} g_1(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} g(-x)=\lim\limits_{x\to a^-} g(x)=0$$

Also,

$$\frac{f_1'(x)}{g_1'(x)}=\frac{f'(-x)}{g'(-x)}$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}\frac{f_1'(x)}{g_1'(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}\frac{f'(-x)}{g'(-x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to a^-}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

According to Result 0 applied to $f_1$ and $g_1$ we have

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}\frac{f_1(x)}{g_1(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}\frac{f_1'(x)}{g_1'(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to a^-}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}\tag{1}$$

But,

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}\frac{f_1(x)}{g_1(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}\frac{f(-x)}{g(-x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to a^-}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\tag{2}$$

Therefore, putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ together we have

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a^-}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to a^-}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$