# Prove $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to -a^-} f(-x)$.

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

> Spivak, Ch. 5, 30 (i) Prove that
>
> $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0^-} f(-x)$$

> To prove this, assume the limit on the left-hand side equals $l$ and
> write out the formal definition of the limit
>
> $$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta>0\ \forall x\ 0<x<\delta\implies
> > |f(x)-l|<\epsilon$$
>
> Now consider a point the satisfies
>
> $$-\delta<x<0$$
>
> Then $0<-x<\delta$, and so $|f(-x)-l|<\epsilon$.
>
> Therefore, we've shown that
>
> $$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta>0\ \forall x,\
> > 0<-x<\delta\implies |f(-x)-l|<\epsilon$$
>
> $$\implies \lim\limits_{x\to 0^-} f(-x)$$

If we replace $0^+$ with $a^+$, what is the corresponding result? It should be

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to -a^-} f(-x)$$

Right?

**Let me try to find some result**

Assume $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} f(x)=l$. This means

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta>0\ \forall x,\ 0<x-a<\delta\implies |f(x)-l|<\epsilon\tag{1}$$

Now consider a number that satisfies

$$-\delta<x-(-a)<0$$

These are the points in the light green region below

[image]

But this means that

$$0<-x-a<\delta$$

and by $(1)$ we have $|f(-x)-l|<\epsilon$

So we've shown that

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta>0\ \forall x,\ 0<x-(-a)<\delta\implies |f(-x)-l|<\epsilon\tag{1}$$

Therefore,

$$\lim\limits_{x\to -a^-} f(-x)=l=\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} f(x)$$

Comment: That seems to be fine.  The key though is that $-0 = 0$ but $-a \ne a$.  So we have a clean symmetry for limits to $0$ from the other side whereas for limits to $a$ from the other side we must be going to a different point.

Comment: Perhaps it is more convenient to apply Heine definition of the limit. Assume $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=g.$ Let $x_n\to -a,$ and $x_n<-a.$ Then $y_n :=-x_n\to a$ and $y_n=-x_n>a.$ Thus $f(-x_n)=f(y_n)\to g.$ Hence $\lim_{x\to -a^-}f(-x)=g.$